# How to tribonacci series value pass in array then print any index value which i want?

Tags: java, arrays, windows, algorithm, indexing

//Program: Tribonacci Series

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Tribonacci
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number till u want Tribonacci series: ");
        int n=sc.nextInt();

        int a = 0,b = 0,c = 1;
        int d = a+b+c;

        System.out.println("\nTribonacci Series: ");
        System.out.print(a+"\t"+b+"\t"+c);

        for(int i=4;i<=n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t"+d);
            a=b;
            b=c;
            c=d;
            d=a+b+c;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

output:

Enter number till u want Tribonacci series: 8

Tribonacci Series:
0       0       1       1       2       4       7       13

now i want this series value pass in array then print any index value which i want,How to do this?

Comment: i'm sorry but how are php and c programming languages related here? Since the above "code" is in java

Comment: Do not use irrelevant tags in your question just to get the attention

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: bro,It was mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a List and keep storing your generated tribonacci numbers into that list. And then can access any tribonacci number by passing index 1 to n.

Try using this code,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number till u want Tribonacci series: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 1;
        int d = a + b + c;
        List<Integer> triboList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number. Number must be greater than zero");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("\nTribonacci Series: ");
        if (n == 1) {
            System.out.print(a);
            triboList.add(a);
        } else if (n == 2) {
            System.out.print(a + "\t" + b);
            triboList.add(a);
            triboList.add(b);
        } else if (n >= 3) {
            triboList.add(a);
            triboList.add(b);
            triboList.add(c);
            System.out.print(a + "\t" + b + "\t" + c);
        }

        for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + d);
            triboList.add(d);
            a = b;
            b = c;
            c = d;
            d = a + b + c;
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and " + n + " to print tribonacci number for that index.");
        int index = sc.nextInt();
        if (index < 1 || index > n) {
            System.out.println("Invalid index. Index can only be 1 to " + n);
        } else {
            System.out.println(triboList.get(index - 1));
        }
    } finally {
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Most welcome and pleased to help. Also, I have updated the answer with code so your program correctly works for all kind of inputs, negative numbers as well as 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on as earlier, even when you entered 1 or 2 for value of n it was printing at least 3 tribonacci numbers.